# Appium inspector displaying blank screen

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am using appium Version 1.4.13 (Draco) Mac version 10.10.5 (14F27). While clicking on the inspector blank screen is displaying.Execution done in simulator.

[image: Blank screen][image: For this page]

Comment: probably the installation of Appium did not complete successfully on your machine resulting in such shortcomings usually. Could you try reinstalling the same once.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually it's not working even after reinstalling.  Any permission or accessibility required from developer?

Comment: My developers using custom cell table. Can you pls help me  for finding xpath of the page.